# Load file once into an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a web based app which in the core is an expert system, and I need to load the rules file to the app only once .. so I need an equivalent to public `static void main() {}` in ASP.NET site to load the file in it .. what is this equivalent and is it exist .. any suggestions are highly welcome

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `Application_Start` event in Global.asax.cs.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in (as @SLaks said) Application_Start. However - be very careful of doing any long operation here as you can run into problems. If this is a long operation, consider starting another thread or pre-processing this information into a table you can quickly load.

Comment: +1 - "running into problems" as in IIS will kill you dead if application startup takes longer than X seconds, definitely need to spin off another thread if startup will take long time

Answer (score 1):

[Auto-Start](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) in ASP.NET 4 was built for this:

> The new "auto start" feature of ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.5 provides a
>   well-defined approach that allows you to perform expensive application
>   startup and pre-cache logic that can run before any end-users hit your
>   application.  This enables you to have your application "warmed up"
>   and ready from the very beginning, and deliver a consistent high
>   performance experience.